# Checking if rectangle B is wholly contained in rectangle A

Tags: c#

Hi guys assist me with checking if rectangle B is wholly contained in rectangle A, here is a sample code to work with:

## Class Rectangle

```
Public class Rectangle
{
    Public int X1 { get; set; }
    Public int X2 { get; set; }
    Public int Y1 { get; set; }
    Public int Y2 { get; set; }

    public bool IsWhollyContained(Rectangle otherRectangle)
    {
        //Write your code here
    }
}
```

## Main Method

```
Public static void main(string[] args)
{
    Rectangle A = new Rectangle { X1 = 2, Y1 = 1, X2 = 4, Y2 = 4}};
    Rectangle B = new Rectangle { X1 = 1, Y1 = 6, X2 = 5, Y2 = 1}};

    bool isContained = B.IsWhollyContained(A);
}
```

The task is to complete method IsWhollyContained. Please assist if you know the answer, the language used is C#. Thanks guys.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Tell us what you have done, write the code, and if you're having problem with it then ask a specific question.

Comment: Well, I'd start here: [Rectangle.Contains Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kh3ee9e(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Even if we were to do your homework for you, the spec is incomplete, so far as I'm concerned. Does a rectangle wholly contain *itself*? I.e. is the boundary inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: Also, `IsWhollyContained` is unclear.  It should be `IsWhollyContainedBy` or `IsWhollyContainedIn`.

Comment: Start with how can you figure out if a line is contained by another line.

Answer (score 0):

sort the rectangle's points to be sure that you're getting the right bound of rectangle than compare the points, try this:

```
public bool IsWhollyContained(Rectangle otherRectangle)
{
    int rec1Xb = X1 > X2 ? X1 : X2;
    int rec1Xs = X1 > X2 ? X2 : X1;

    int rec1Yb = Y1 > Y2 ? Y1 : Y2;
    int rec1Ys = Y1 > Y2 ? Y2 : Y1;


    int rec2Xb = otherRectangle.X1 < otherRectangle.X2 ? otherRectangle.X1 : otherRectangle.X2;
    int rec2Xs = otherRectangle.X1 < otherRectangle.X2 ? otherRectangle.X2 : otherRectangle.X1;

    int rec2Yb = otherRectangle.Y1 < otherRectangle.Y2 ? otherRectangle.Y1 : otherRectangle.Y2;
    int rec2Ys = otherRectangle.Y1 < otherRectangle.Y2 ? otherRectangle.Y2 : otherRectangle.Y1;

    return  rec1Xs >= rec2Xs &&
            rec1Xb <= rec2Xb &&
            rec1Ys >= rec2Ys &&
            rec1Yb <= rec2Yb;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Conrado Costa.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code if you are using the `System.Drawing Rectangle`

```
Rectangle rect1, rect2;
// initialize them
if(rect1.Contains(rect2))
{
    // do...
}
```

Here is the link [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.contains(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you are using your own rectangle you may check if all the corner points from the first rectangle belong to the second one.

```
bool PointInsideRectangle(Point pt, double y0, double x0, double y1, double x1)
{
   if (x1 < x0)
    {
        return pt.X < x0 && pt.X > x1 && pt.Y < y0 && pt.Y > y1;
    }

    // it crosses the date line
    return (pt.X < x0 || pt.X > x1) && pt.Y < y0 && pt.Y > y1;        
}
```

Or you need to only check the x0,y0 from the first rectangle to compare with the x0,y0 from the second rectangle, and with, height from the first rectangle and compare it with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that X1, X2, Y1 and Y2 are the coordinates for the lower left and upper right corners of your rectangle.
If another rectangle is supposed to be located inside the first one, the following conditions must be fulfilled:

```
rectangle1.X1 < rectangle2.X1
rectangle1.Y1 < rectangle2.Y1
rectangle1.X2 > rectangle2.X2
rectangle1.Y2 > rectangle2.Y2
```

But you don't need to store all those coordinates in your rectangle. System.Drawing has something called `Point`, you can assign an X- and a Y-Coordinate to that. But if you're already including System.Drawing you can just go with what Hazem Abdullah suggested.